# Create Vulkan Instance/Device with all supported extensions/features enabled

Tags: c, gpu, vulkan

In Vulkan, while creating a `vkInstance` or a `vkDevice` all extensions that will be used must be specified to be enabled during instance/device creation. Similarly, all physical device features required must be specified while creating a `vkDevice`. So my question is, **is there any real reason against simply enabling all availble extensions/features**, similarly to how in OpenGL all extensions/features are always enabled and the application simply queries for their support? By this I mean using all extensions returned by `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties`, `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties` and similar.

I ask because I think that enabling all available extensions/features is simpler than using a different approach and I am wondering if it is inferior, for example causes some performance overhead, to enabling only required (or optionally used) features/extesions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> enabling all available extensions/features is simpler than using a different approach

What different approach? You still need to test if the extension exists before actually using the function pointer to it, don't you?

> is there any real reason against simply enabling all availble extensions/features, similarly to [...] OpenGL

The whole purpose of using Vulkan is that you get fine control over every single detail of interfacing with your GPU. From extensions to whether or not to create a depth buffer, to explicit multi-threaded & multi-device synchronization, it's up to you to use exactly what you need and nothing more.

Nothing is stopping you from using OpenGL if you prefer an easier journey, especially if you won't go the extra mile (or 10 miles, as it were). It's much easier to write performant applications in OpenGL than it is to write even moderately performant Vulkan applications.

Comment: "It's much easier to write performant applications in OpenGL than it is to write even moderately performant Vulkan applications." I didn't consider this point. Until now I thought of Vulkan as an obvious performance win over OpenGL. I suppose I will have to think it over again...

Comment: By a "different approach" I meant that the application is made of many modules and every one of them possibly needs different extensions/features and their needs must be consolidated at instance/device creation. Its easier to just check later. I don't claim though that its better.

Comment: Another point to consider is that learning OpenGL isn't wasted if you're still planning on learning Vulkan later. While it's more similar to DirectX in architecture, most of the OpenGL mechanics will port over, at least conceptually.

Comment: "their needs must be consolidated at instance/device creation" -- you'll find that a lot in Vulkan, for example the pipeline that needs to be fully defined (with textures, shaders, rasterization options, queues, stages, everything) before you can render anything, and any change in parameters will require an entirely new pipeline. It's just how it, and the GPU, works.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you are not allowed to enable certain combination of features and extensions..

Secondly, even just enabling a feature can incur some kind of an overhad. Notably, you do not want all those robust image\buffer features enabled.